# List all the possible combinations

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a question related to the combination.

I am actually developing a ecommerce site and I have a function to allow customer create product variant.

For example: Black Pant 34W 30L, Black Pant 38W 32L, White Pant 34W 30l. Those are defined as product variants.

Assume my pant has 3 options, and they are color, waist size and length.

I now have 3 list.

```
ListA = {"black", "white", "red"} //For the color
ListB = {30,32,34,36,38} //For the waist
ListC ={28,30,32,34} //For the length
```

My question is how can I list all the possible combinations?

My desired result should be look like  {{black,30,28},{black,30,30},{black,30,32},{white,34
,30}}

P.S. The tricky part is that I don't know how many options customer will assign to this product. The count of the option might be just 1, which is the easiest; it could be more than 3...

**Problem Solved**

Since we don't know how many options we will have. Therefore, we don't know how many for loop we are going to use. In other word, it turns to a typical Cartesian Products.

For more information, you can read from these two links.
http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2010/07/28/linq-cartesian-1
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx Seems relevant

Comment: Have you looked at how other ecommerce system do it? dashCommerce has a similar option to generate SKUs from product variants.

Comment: I did got a NopCommerce and learned some idea from it.

Comment: Many thanks to both of you. Thank you very much for the clue. Cartesian Products is the keyword!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated in the comments Eric Lippert has a blog post named [Computing a Cartesian Product with LINQ](http://ericlippert.com/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq/) that explains how to solve your problem. You need an extension method to compute the cartesian product:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences) {
  IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> result = new [] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() };
  foreach (var sequence in sequences) {
    var localSequence = sequence;
    result = result.SelectMany(
      _ => localSequence,
      (seq, item) => seq.Concat(new[] { item })
    );
  }
  return result;
}
```

Then you need a sequence of sequences to perform the product over. In your case you have both strings and integers in your sequences so the common base type `T` has to be `Object`.

```
var sequences = new[] {
  new Object[] { "black", "white", "red" },
  new Object[] { 30, 32, 34, 36, 38 },
  new Object[] { 28, 30, 32, 34 }
};
```

To compute the Cartesian product you simply invoke the extension method:

```
var result = sequences.CartesianProduct();
```

When you enumerate the result it is computed on the fly (lazily). If you prefer to create a list of lists you need to call `ToList()` after `Concat` and also before returning `result` from the extension method.

Comment: Thanks buddy, you save the world!

Comment: @Eric Lippert how about using expression trees for cartezian product computation? I think it is far more powerfull than the LINQ functional version: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31376699/2746390

Comment: I had to put ToList() after Concat for it to work properly. (.NET Framework 4.6)

Comment: @ReinierDG: Information about when to use `ToList` should be in the last paragraph of my answer.